# Is there any progress in the study of the relationship between Rubik's cube and quark?

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

After Golomb discovered the relationship between Rubik's cube and quark, Anthony E. Durham improved it. Is there a link to Anthony E. Durham's work? May be the principal bundles can explain the relationship between Rubik's cube and quark(https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/XFVFpFclxIM/m/F-kzjv4ad6QJ)? Any information on this is welcome. thank you.

Comment: You might find it interesting to [search this topic on Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=rubik%27s+cube+quarks).